# how to pass function output to another function

Tags: javascript, casperjs

was playing around with casperjs lately and didnt manage to complete the below code, was using child_process and need to get function output to be passed to another function any ideas ?

success call variable scope limited to success function only, and i cant use it anywhere in my code

```
casper.repeat(3, function() {
    this.sendKeys(x('//*[@id="text-area"]'), testvalue.call(this)); //  testvalue.call(this) dosnt input anything here
})

casper.echo(testvalue.call(this)); // Print output successfully

function testvalue() {
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn
    var execFile = require("child_process").execFile
    var child = spawn("/usr/bin/php", ["script.php"])

    child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // Print output successfully
        return JSON.stringify(data); // Problem is here i cant use Data any where in code except this scope
    })
}
```

Comment: Is because data it part of the scope as an argument of the function. If you return something like `return { json: JSON.stringify(data), data: data }` that will make the function return an object which will contain both so you can then access `data` outside this scope.

Comment: That didnt work for me, can you provide full example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `spawn` is an asynchronous process, you need to use a callback for `testvalue`. Returning something inside the event handler doesn't return it from `testvalue`.

The other problem is that you need to remain in the CasperJS control flow. This is why I use `testvaluedone` to determine if the spawned process is done executing and I can `completeData`.

```
casper.repeat(3, function() {
    var testvaluedone = false;
    var completeData = "";
    testvalue();
    this.waitFor(function check(){
        return testvaluedone;
    }, function then(){
        this.sendKeys(x('//*[@id="text-area"]'), completeData);
    }); // maybe tweak the timeout a little
});

var testvaluedone, completeData;
function testvalue() {
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    var execFile = require("child_process").execFile;
    var child = spawn("/usr/bin/php", ["script.php"]);

    child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
        completeData += JSON.stringify(data);
    });
    child.on("exit", function(code){
        testvaluedone = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: I added the actual call to `testvalue`.